# Increase cpu usage in virtualbox without VT

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Virtualbox to virtualise a Windows server on my Debian box. My computer neither has VT nor AMD Virtualization technology.
When I look with top the virtualbox process never goes over 100% cpu usage. But I have 4 cores, so the maximum cpu usage would be 400%.
Is there a possibility to increase the limit for the cpu usage of the Virtualbox process to over 100%?

Comment: Did you assign more than one virtual CPU to your Windows server guest?

Answer (score 1):

"*...so the maximum cpu usage would be 400%*"

False. 100 = all the cores on max. If only one core would be used, the load would be 25%.